# No se encuentra el recurso en c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Tengo el siguiente programa que muestra datos JSON.

Código del `Controller`:

```
using MVCCuartoDia2.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVCCuartoDia2.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Customer
        public JsonResult getJson()
        {
            Customer objCustomer = new Customer();
            objCustomer.CustomerCode = "c001";
            return Json(objCustomer, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        public ActionResult MostrarJson()
        {
           return View("AprenderJquery");

         }
    }
}
```

Clase `Customer`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCCuartoDia2.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        private string _CustomerCode;

        public string CustomerCode
        {
            get { return _CustomerCode; }
            set {  _CustomerCode = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Vista `AprenderJquery`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>AprenderJquery</title>    
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="ver dato JSON" onclick="return getJson()" /> 
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getJson()
        {
            $.getJSON("/Customer/getJson", null, Display1)
            return true;
        }
        function Display1(data)
        {
            alert(data.CustomerCode);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Código del `Routeconfig`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MVCCuartoDia2
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "MostrarJson", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Caundo ejecuto el proyecto me dice:

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. No se encuentra el recurso.
>   Descripción: HTTP 404. El recurso que está buscando (o una de sus
>   dependencias) se puede haber quitado, haber cambiado de nombre o no
>   estar disponible temporalmente. Revise la dirección URL siguiente y
>   asegúrese de que está escrita correctamente.
>
> Dirección URL solicitada: /

Sin embargo tanto el nombre del `Controller` como el `Action` están bien puestos, ¿por qué no me funciona?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la URL que intentas accerder? Debe ser algo como TuSitio/Customer/MostrarJson

Comment: localhost:XXXXX//Customer/MostrarJson

Comment: Pareciera no se esta cargando MVC, porque tu código está correcto (ya lo validé en mi compu). Cómo estas ejecutando el servico (IIS Express o IIS Server)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema está aqui:

```
$.getJSON("/Customer/getJson", null, Display1);
```

Solución:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("getJson", "Customer")';
$.getJSON(url, null, Display1);
```

Siempre que utilices URLs en JavaScript que apunten a recursos en **ASP.net MVC**, utiliza los `@Url.Action` y `@Url.Content` porque así el framework se encarga de generar las rutas de donde vayas a poner en producción tu sistema.

Si andas iniciando con ASP.net MVC, hice un workshop de 4 horas 4 minutos y 4 segundos en https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY que contiene el código fuente en Github. Lleva unas clases en http://mva.microsoft.com donde te enseñan muy cheeere y son gratuitas, definitivamente lo recomiendo.

Comment: muchas gracias. Gracias por los links.

Comment: de nada hermano, estamos para servir, éxitos con el desarrollo! a darle con todo el power 2.0!!! lml